# Load geojson on google maps api

Tags: javascript, json, google-maps, google-maps-api-3, geojson

```js
 $(document).ready(function(){
  $("button").click(function(){
    $("#apartado-api").toggle();
  });
});

           function initMap() {
             var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map'), {
             center: {lat:  40.416775, lng:-3.703790},
             zoom: 14
           });
 
 
 
 map.data.loadGeoJson('map.json');
 
 
 ////////////////////////////////////////////this would be on a separate json file called map.json. I want to bring this file to the js one and add the marker to the map
 {
  "type": "FeatureCollection",
  "features": [
    {
      "type": "Feature",
      "geometry": {
        "type": "Point",
        "coordinates": [ -3.717451,  40.469264 ]
      },
      "properties": {
       "name": "Peluquería Canina Pet Shop",
         "address": "Calle Valdesangil, 9, 28039 Madrid"
      }
    },
    {
      "type": "Feature",
      "geometry": {
        "type": "Point",
        "coordinates": [ -3.649130, 40.476251 ]
      },
      "properties": {
        "name": "Zoolife Veterinaria",
        "address": "Av. de Menéndez Pelayo, 9, 28009 Madrid"
      }
    },
    {
      "type": "Feature",
      "geometry": {
        "type": "Point",
        "coordinates": [-3.668233, 40.478529 ]
      },
      "properties": {
        "name": "La Caseta",
           "address": "Calle de Arturo Soria, 320, 28033 Madrid"
      }
    }
  ]
}
```

```css
 /* Always set the map height explicitly to define the size of the div
       * element that contains the map. */
       #map {
        height: 100%;
      }
      /* Optional: Makes the sample page fill the window. */
      html, body {
        height: 100%;
        margin: 0;
        padding: 0;
      }

      #boton-mapa-api{
        z-index: 1000;
        position: absolute;
        top: 60px;
        left: 15px;
        width: 400px;
        margin: 0;
        cursor: pointer;
      }

      #apartado-api{
        width: 400px;
        height: 400px;
        z-index: 900;
        position: absolute;
        top: 70px;
        left: 15px;
        background: rgb(255, 255, 255);
        border-radius: 20px;
        -webkit-box-shadow: 2px 9px 11px 0px rgba(0,0,0,0.07);
        -moz-box-shadow: 2px 9px 11px 0px rgba(0,0,0,0.07);
        box-shadow: 2px 9px 11px 0px rgba(0,0,0,0.07);
      }

      /*comienzo botón estandar*/
.boton-general {
    font-family: 'ABeeZee', sans-serif;
    font-size: 1em;
    color: white;
    letter-spacing: 1px;
    padding: 15px;
    margin: 20px;
    font-weight: 900;
    border: none;
    border-radius: 50px;
    /*gradiente*/
    background: rgb(123, 228, 149);
    background: linear-gradient(175deg, rgba(123, 228, 149, 1) 32%, rgba(64, 185, 184, 1) 100%);
    transition: all 0.3s ease-in-out;
    /*sombras*/
    box-shadow: 0px 6px 12px 0px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.12);
    -webkit-box-shadow: 7px 6px 14px 0px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.12);
    -moz-box-shadow: 7px 6px 14px 0px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.12);

}

/*estados del botón*/
.boton-general:hover {
    letter-spacing: 2.5px;
    border-radius: 10px;
}



.boton-general:focus {
    outline: 0;

}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <title>Animal Rooms</title>
    <meta name="viewport" content="initial-scale=1.0, user-scalable=no">
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css">
  </head>

  <body>
    <button id="boton-mapa-api" class="boton-general">¿Qué buscas?</button>

    <div id="apartado-api"></div>
    <!-- div del mapa -->
    <div id="map"></div>
    <!-- div del mapa -->

    <!-- link API -->
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.4.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
   
    <script async defer
    src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?key=MY_API_KEY&callback=initMap">
    </script>
    <script
    src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.4.1.min.js"
    integrity="sha256-CSXorXvZcTkaix6Yvo6HppcZGetbYMGWSFlBw8HfCJo="
    crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
     <!-- js de la API -->
    <script src="script.js"></script>
  </body>
</html>
```

I've been reading the documentation for the google maps js API and I can't figure this out. I want to load a geojson file to the map so it can show all the markers, but in the documentation (shown below) it uses a url. How can I do the same but with a local file (using my own geojson)?

> This is the google api documentation

```
var map;
  function initMap() {
    map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map'), {
      zoom: 2,
      center: new google.maps.LatLng(2.8,-187.3),
      mapTypeId: 'terrain'
    });


    map.data.loadGeoJson('google.json');
```

> This is my geojson. According to the console, the error is in  *"type": "FeatureCollection"* (the ":")

```
 {
  "type": "FeatureCollection",
  "features": [
    {
      "type": "Feature",
      "geometry": {
        "type": "Point",
        "coordinates": [ -3.717451,  40.469264 ]
      },
      "properties": {
       "name": "Peluquería Canina Pet Shop",
         "address": "Calle Valdesangil, 9, 28039 Madrid"
      }
    },
    {
      "type": "Feature",
      "geometry": {
        "type": "Point",
        "coordinates": [ -3.649130, 40.476251 ]
      },
      "properties": {
        "name": "Zoolife Veterinaria",
        "address": "Av. de Menéndez Pelayo, 9, 28009 Madrid"
      }
    },
    {
      "type": "Feature",
      "geometry": {
        "type": "Point",
        "coordinates": [-3.668233, 40.478529 ]
      },
      "properties": {
        "name": "La Caseta",
           "address": "Calle de Arturo Soria, 320, 28033 Madrid"
      }
    }
  ]
}
```

[Console error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0JO0N.jpg)

[Console error geoJSON](https://i.stack.imgur.com/PE2ny.png)

[View on http://geojson.io/](https://i.stack.imgur.com/LiM4s.jpg)

[View on my local server](https://i.stack.imgur.com/kfDjB.png)

Comment: Is your GeoJSON in a file on your server? Or are you asking how to load it as a variable from your script?

Comment: Did you change the URL to point to your file? Is your file on a web server?

Comment: Sorry, I uploaded the wrong documentation (I edited the question). The correct one says I should use *map.data.loadGeoJson('google.json')* to load the data into the map but the cosole  gives the error 'Cannot read property 'loadGeoJson' of undefined' . My GeoJSON is not on a server, It's on a local file. Thank you for the help  in advance.

Comment: The error I get (on Chrome) is: `Access to XMLHttpRequest at 'file:///<path to file>' from origin 'null' has been blocked by CORS policy: Cross origin requests are only supported for protocol schemes: http, data, chrome, chrome-extension, https.`.  I get a similar error in Firefox. Once I get the GeoJSON to load, it is obvious that the coordinates are "backwards" (latitude and longitude are reversed, in GeoJSON, the format is `[longitude, latitude]`.  I don't ever see the error you report (`Cannot read property 'loadGeoJson' of undefined`)

Comment: Now the first error doesnt show and I get another one, I uploaded it on the question. It says I have a SyntaxError on  "type": "FeatureCollection" (the ":" part). Also, I asked my teacher why the markers wont show and he said it had to do with access control and the coord? I'm guessing thats the "Access to XMLHttpRequest at 'file:///<path to file>' ..." error. Do you know how to solve that?  Again, thank you for all the help.

Comment: Also I dont get the "Access to XMLHttpRequest at 'file:///<path to file>' ..." error on my console

Comment: Unless you fixed the issue with the coordinates, the markers are likely there, but not where you expect them to be. Although looking at your pictures, the GeoJSON has changed.  Please update your question to include a [mcve].

Comment: I updated the question again, and added 2 pictures ( one is how it looks on geojson.io to check if the json is correct, and how I see it on my computer with no markers). Also, I change the coordinates to be correct now.

Comment: How are you incluing the GeoSON? What does your code (now) look like? (Please, not a picture) Can you provide a [mcve] that demonstrates your issue?

Comment: Looks like the syntax error you report is due to including your GeoJSON in a javascript file directly (not assigning it to a variable).

Comment: I uploaded a snippet code. I thought the pictures were helping, sorry.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's no problem with your json file nor with the way you load it. Try running this [codesandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/stoic-cori-m9exg) for demonstration in vanilla JS.

As for your own jquery code, it works fine if you format it properly and use the right files, placed correctly at root-level. Please try the code below for each file. Hope this helps!

index.html

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
    <title>Animal Rooms</title>
    <meta name="viewport" content="initial-scale=1.0, user-scalable=no">
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css">
</head>

<body>
    <button id="boton-mapa-api" class="boton-general">¿Qué buscas?</button>

    <div id="apartado-api"></div>
    <!-- div del mapa -->
    <div id="map"></div>
    <!-- div del mapa -->

    <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.4.1.min.js" integrity="sha256-CSXorXvZcTkaix6Yvo6HppcZGetbYMGWSFlBw8HfCJo=" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>

    <script async defer src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?callback=initMap">
    </script>

    <!-- js de la API -->
    <script src="script.js"></script>
</body>

</html>
```

script.js

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $("button").click(function() {
        $("#apartado-api").toggle();
    });
});

function initMap() {
    var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map'), {
        center: { lat: 40.416775, lng: -3.703790 },
        zoom: 12
    });
    map.data.loadGeoJson('map.json');
}
```

style.css

```
#map {
    height: 100%;
}

html,
body {
    height: 100%;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
}

#boton-mapa-api {
    z-index: 1000;
    position: absolute;
    top: 60px;
    left: 15px;
    width: 400px;
    margin: 0;
    cursor: pointer;
}

#apartado-api {
    width: 400px;
    height: 400px;
    z-index: 900;
    position: absolute;
    top: 70px;
    left: 15px;
    background: rgb(255, 255, 255);
    border-radius: 20px;
    -webkit-box-shadow: 2px 9px 11px 0px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.07);
    -moz-box-shadow: 2px 9px 11px 0px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.07);
    box-shadow: 2px 9px 11px 0px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.07);
}

/*comienzo botón estandar*/

.boton-general {
    font-family: 'ABeeZee', sans-serif;
    font-size: 1em;
    color: white;
    letter-spacing: 1px;
    padding: 15px;
    margin: 20px;
    font-weight: 900;
    border: none;
    border-radius: 50px;
    /*gradiente*/
    background: rgb(123, 228, 149);
    background: linear-gradient(175deg, rgba(123, 228, 149, 1) 32%, rgba(64, 185, 184, 1) 100%);
    transition: all 0.3s ease-in-out;
    /*sombras*/
    box-shadow: 0px 6px 12px 0px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.12);
    -webkit-box-shadow: 7px 6px 14px 0px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.12);
    -moz-box-shadow: 7px 6px 14px 0px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.12);
}

/*estados del botón*/

.boton-general:hover {
    letter-spacing: 2.5px;
    border-radius: 10px;
}

.boton-general:focus {
    outline: 0;
}
```

map.json

```
 {
     "type": "FeatureCollection",
     "features": [{
             "type": "Feature",
             "geometry": {
                 "type": "Point",
                 "coordinates": [-3.717451, 40.469264]
             },
             "properties": {
                 "name": "Peluquería Canina Pet Shop",
                 "address": "Calle Valdesangil, 9, 28039 Madrid"
             }
         },
         {
             "type": "Feature",
             "geometry": {
                 "type": "Point",
                 "coordinates": [-3.649130, 40.476251]
             },
             "properties": {
                 "name": "Zoolife Veterinaria",
                 "address": "Av. de Menéndez Pelayo, 9, 28009 Madrid"
             }
         },
         {
             "type": "Feature",
             "geometry": {
                 "type": "Point",
                 "coordinates": [-3.668233, 40.478529]
             },
             "properties": {
                 "name": "La Caseta",
                 "address": "Calle de Arturo Soria, 320, 28033 Madrid"
             }
         }
     ]
 }
```